# Accessing files attributes vs accessing sqlite records

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sqlite, nsfilemanager

In one of our apps I was asked to keep record of the last modified date of images . That way I can check with the server if a certain image has changed and update my cache accordingly.

My first approach was to access the files attributes and perform a comparison but a few places online mentioned a drastic bottleneck in terms of latency.

My second choice was to create a SQLite table to manage it. (Using [fmdb](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb))

I've decided to write a simple latency test. In the next test I'm accessing 500 file attributes and 500 sqlite records:

```
- (void)latencyTest
{
    NSMutableArray *arrayTest1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *arrayTest2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    FMResultSet *results = [_database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM `tb_media`"];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS"];
    NSLog(@"Time1: %@",[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
    int i=1;
    while(i<501)
    {
        NSString *test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/_media/media/19/%d.jpg",_outputPath,i];
        NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:test error:nil];
        NSDate *dateX = [attributes fileModificationDate];
        [arrayTest1 addObject:dateX];
        i++;
    }
    NSLog(@"Time2: %@",[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
    while([results next])
    {        
        NSDate *myDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[results intForColumn:@"last_update"]];
        [arrayTest2 addObject:myDate];
    }
    NSLog(@"Time3: %@",[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
}
```

Results:

```
    //iPhone 5 (Actual Device) 500 Pics

    Files Start:                 05-03-2014 09:31:20:375 
    Files End & Sqlite start:    05-03-2014 09:31:20:491 
    Sqlite end:                  05-03-2014 09:31:20:507

    Files Start:                 05-03-2014 09:31:56:305 
    Files End & Sqlite start:    05-03-2014 09:31:56:421 
    Sqlite end:                  05-03-2014 09:31:56:437

    Files Start:                 05-03-2014 09:32:19:053 
    Files End & Sqlite start:    05-03-2014 09:32:19:170 
    Sqlite end:                  05-03-2014 09:32:19:187
```

As you can see the results are pretty much the same. 
My questions are:

1. I was under the assumption that accessing one file at a time using `attributesOfItemAtPath` will
   take a lot longer than sql. Am I missing something?
2. Does `attributesOfItemAtPath` really accessing the file or the iOS
   filesystem keeps all the attributes in some sort of database for
   easy access?
3. After seeing the above results I've decided to go with the
   `attributesOfItemAtPath` method. Is there anything else I'm not
   considering passing on sqlite?

Comment: I wasn't aware of fileModificationDate method, thanks :-)

Comment: What hardware are you using for your test? SSDs will perform significantly better than the flash memory in an iOS device. That said 500 isn't that many files, even for embedded hardware. Do you expect that magnitude is within the bounds of your cache? Or will you have to scale this up to many thousands of images?

Comment: @ImHuntingWabbits That's weird, the SSD performed slower than my iPhone 5 but to be honest the simulator does not really interests me, only actual devices. While trying to query more than 500 files I reached some sort of limit with sqlite with the error "SQLite error: too many terms in compound SELECT" so I'll keep that on 500 for now.

Comment: Your test results don't seem to indicate that. Simulator was ~1ms for sqlite and ~9ms file system, but device above looks like ~17ms for sqlite and ~130ms for filesystem. The device results around what I would expect for current gen hardware, slower on things like current iPod touches and older iPhones / iPads.

Comment: You are totally right. I confused the posted results with other, slower results I did on a non-ssd mac. I'll update the question with my hardware.

Comment: Depending on your use case a cache might help you speed things up here and keep thing simple -- You can store it in NSUserDefaults or on disk with NSCoding serialisation pretty easily. In terms of your sqlite results, you would get much faster results using preprepared sqlite statements (sqlite3_stmt). In FMDB you can turn on caching with the shouldCacheStatements property.

Comment: I'm not getting it, you've decided to go with the `attributesOfItemAtPath` method, because it takes longer? I feel stupid now... Also, shouldn't you consider the time used by `executeQuery`?

Comment: @Merlevede On the device tests attributesOfItemAtPath takes the same time as sqlite. I'm considering the time of the all process.

Comment: Please clarify your question.  In every case above the file access scheme was significantly slower than the SQLite one.  Without further clarification your questions are meaningless.

Comment: @HotLicks Sorry for not being clear. 0.100 of a second delay between the two options above is far from significant for me. (specially if 500 pics at a time is the maximum number of files I'll access)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before I discuss the solution , there are certain problems in your evaluation strategy.

1) You haven't incorporated time taken by NSLog and while loop. 75% of time is taken by them 
whereas you just want to compare intForColumn vs attributesOfItemAtPath. A correct way of doing this is run instruments  [Timer Profiler](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/TimeProfilerInstrument/TimeProfilerInstrument.html) and compare time for retrieving a single record.

2) You have used FMDB as a file manager. Internally FMDB serialize data in a file. The core of FMDB / SQL Lite lies in its data structure specially indexing which you haven't used at all. 
So even if you compare time taken for your records you will observer FMDB is taking more time than file manager because of extra overhead to serialize data in specific format.

3) Access time of X number of records is compared by the # of times access is done to disk (hard drive) not heap. What you are doing is heap access of data store in both cases. So you won't be able to see any difference at all.

Does this mean File Manager is better than FMDB , absolutely not!!
Here are few reasons why :

FMDB performs well only when its configured to do so. 
The core of FMDB lies in two things paging (caching into heap) and index.
Let me explain you each one at a time.

1)Assume that you are trying to access timestamp for 100 images. Where each image is having 1000 timestamps. This mean you have to make 100*1000 = 100,000 access to data store. 
If images are small then Filemanager will load the file into heap and access will be faster than FMDB but if you don't have sufficient heap space your application will issue memory warning and access file from disk rather than cache which is significantly slower.

So its a binary state either all from heap or all from disk

FMDB outperforms this state and retrieves partial records depending upon the available heap space. This makes access faster when you have a huge chuck of records.

The ideal way to test this scenario is to run your fucntion latencyTest for atleast 10,000 images (not timestamp). This way the log times and iteration speed will be negligible as compared to overall time taken.

2) Index structure, this goes back to the basics of SQL Lite. You might want to add an extra attribute call as number of access to images and index your table on that. This will boost up perforce significantly. Not quite possible with Filemeanger.

Solution  which I recommend.
1) If you have data less than 2 MB (images plus timestamp ) go for Filemenager

2) If data is > 2MB go for Core Data / FMDB.

Core data has additional performance tuning for multithreaded environment and many more additional features like seamless integration for encryption.

Answer (score 0):

First, as @kunal said, your benchmarking method is not deterministic and can mislead your decisions.

Having said that, attributesOfItemAtPath: does a little bit of overhead if you only need the modified date and performance is really an issue for you. What you can do is use [lstat](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/stat.2.html) instead. This is similar to your case (Note that I removed the arrays to avoid unneeded overhead on the benchmark):

```
#import <sys/stat.h>

- (void)latencyTest
{
    // *********************** Test 1 ***********************************//
    double t = CACurrentMediaTime();
    for (NSInteger i = 1; i < 748; i++)
    {
        NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:kMediaPath, i];
        NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:path
                                                                                    error:nil];
        NSDate *dateX = [attributes fileModificationDate];
    }
    double total = CACurrentMediaTime() - t;
    NSLog(@"Total time fileManager: %fs, average per read: %fs", total, total / 747.f);

    // *********************** Test 2 ***********************************//
    struct stat linfo;
    t = CACurrentMediaTime();
    for (NSInteger i = 1; i < 748; i++)
    {
        NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:kMediaPath, i];
        lstat([path cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], &linfo);
        NSDate *dateX = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:linfo.st_mtime];
    }
    total = CACurrentMediaTime() - t;
    NSLog(@"Total time lstat: %fs, average per read: %fs", total, total / 747.f);
}
```

For an input of 748 images, my results are:

```
// Simulator (iOS 7.1)

Total time fileManager: 0.061365s, average per read: 0.000082s
Total time lstat: 0.004313s, average per read: 0.000006s

// iPhone 5s Device (iOS 7.1)

Total time fileManager: 0.019299, average per read: 0.000026
Total time lstat: 0.008520, average per read: 0.000011
```